# Assign Projects to multiple Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm just getting started in rails and I'm stuck with a little problem.

Imagine you have to Types of Users: Client and Admin. Both are stored in the same User Model with an boolean (admin=true/false). That's how I differentiate between those. So now there are Projects. These are just posts with multiple attributes like Name, Description, Category...

I want my admins to see all the Projects and he should have the ability to edit those project but at the same time I want to show the Client User only the Projects he is assigned to and he shouldn't be able to edit those.

So concluding: Admin -> See all posts and be able to edit and assign Clients to them

Client -> See Projects he is assigned to but not able to edit those. He should only see the ones he is assigned to.

How do I do it?

Comment: Have you googled this? You can hardly be the first to want different roles in his application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Project belong to a User. That entails:

- generate a migration to add the DB column (run this command):

  ```
  $ rails g migration AddUserToProjects user:references
  ```
- add the association to your `Project` model (`app/models/project.rb`):

  ```
  belongs_to :user
  ```
- add the association to your `User` model (`app/models/user.rb`):

  ```
  has_many :projects
  ```

In your Projects controller, you want to have actions for the following:

- a list of projects for a user
- an admin's list of *all* projects

Those could look like this (`app/controllers/projects_controller.rb`):

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :verify_admin_status, :only => [:admin_list]

  def user_list
    @projects = current_user.projects
  end

  def admin_list
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  private
    def verify_admin_status
      unless current_user.admin
        raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')  # or whatever other error you want, i.e. 403
      end
    end
end
```

Add the routes to your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
get 'projects/mine',  :to => 'projects#user_list'
get 'projects/admin', :to => 'projects#admin_list'
```

Take a similar approach for defining the edit actions: check that the user who's trying to access it is an admin by using the `verify_admin_status` callback, then select (or update) the Project record.

Answer (score 0):

check in your views and controller actions

```
if current_user.admin
```